# How to transfor query from SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have many to many relationship, table Product, table Category and join table ProductCategory.

I need to convert this SQL query to LINQ C#:

```
    Select TOP 3 Categories.id, Categories.Description, avg(Products.Price) as MeanPrice, count(Products.IsAvailable) as NumberOfAvailableProducts
FROM Categories
INNER JOIN ProductCategories on  Categories.Id = 
           ProductCategories.CategoryId
INNER JOIN Products on Products.Id = ProductCategories.CategoryId
WHERE Products.IsAvailable='true'
GROUP BY Categories.Id, Categories.Description
ORDER BY MeanPrice DESC
```

I would appreciate help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many examples in the Internet for you to start learning how to write LINQ effectively (including the post from NetMage above).

But I would give you the examples anyway, based on your case above, with an assumption that this T-SQL of yours :

```
INNER JOIN Products on Products.Id = ProductCategories.CategoryId
```

might've been a typo, because what you really meant was maybe like this :

```
INNER JOIN Products on Products.Id = ProductCategories.ProductId
```

So, this is the snippet when you ask me how could I do that in LINQ :

```
var query = (from finalq in
                (
                    from cat in categories
                    join procat in
                        // Join [ProductCategories] with [Products] first
                        (
                            from pc in productcategories
                            join p in products on pc.ProductId equals p.Id
                            where p.IsAvailable == "True"
                            select new
                            {
                                CategoryId = pc.CategoryId,
                                ProductId = p.Id,
                                ProductPrice = p.Price
                            }
                        )
                    // And then join the result with [Categories]
                    on cat.Id equals procat.CategoryId
                    select new
                    {
                        CategoryId = cat.Id,
                        CategoryDescription = cat.Description,
                        ProductPrice = procat.ProductPrice
                    }
                )
            // Then aggregate it to get the final result
            group finalq by new { finalq.CategoryId, finalq.CategoryDescription } into finalGroup
            orderby finalGroup.Average(c => c.ProductPrice) descending
            select new
            {
                CategoryId = finalGroup.Key.CategoryId,
                CategoryDescription = finalGroup.Key.CategoryDescription,
                ProductPrice = finalGroup.Average(c => c.ProductPrice),
                NumberOfAvailableProducts = finalGroup.Count()
            }
        )
        // And take the TOP 3 rows (I know it's ugly but I don't have a choice)
        .Take(3);
```

So, that's it. I hope you can get something from my post here, and later may create your own, a better version of this quick example.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, somehow i succeeded last night to make good linq query but this approach is much better, i will use it from now on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate FROM subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, translating monadic operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, etc) into functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new {` ... `}`) for multiple columns.
5. Left Join is simulated by using a into join_variable and doing another from from the join variable followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
6. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator and a null test.
7. Translate `IN` to `.Contains()` and `NOT IN` to `!`...`Contains()`
8. `SELECT *` must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
9. `SELECT` fields must be replaced with `select new {` ... `}` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
10. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an extension method.